# Exclude one function from another

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to find a function, $g(n)$ that will include all the natural values except those in $f(n)$?

$$f(n) = 3n$$

$$g(n) = 1,2,4,5,7,8,10...$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function exists, but I guess that what you want is an expression.

$$g(n)=3\left\lfloor\frac {n-1}2\right\rfloor+2-2\left(\frac n2-\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor\right)$$

Comment: Can you please explain how did you calculate it?

Comment: Well, my first idea was noting that the sequence $1,2,4,5,7,8,\ldots$ can be separated into pairs: $1,2$, then $4,5$, then $7,8$ etc. Then, one should divide $n$ by $2$ (integer division, I mean) and multiply by $3$ and after that, add $1$ or $2$ depending on the parity of $n$. Finally I had to adjust some details of the formula to work.

Comment: Tnx, this is very interesting.